# Create a new dataframe with k copies of each row appended to itself

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe with n rows:

```
Index  data1  data2  data3
0      x0     x0     x0
1      x1     x1     x1
2      x2     x2     x2
...
n      xn     xn     xn
```

How do I create a new dataframe (using pandas) with k copies of each row appended to itself:

```
Index  data1  data2  data3
0      x0     x0     x0
1      x0     x0     x0
...
k-1    x0     x0     x0
k      x1     x1     x1
k+1    x1     x1     x1
...
2k-1   x1     x1     x1
2k     x2     x2     x2
...
```

Answer (score 2):

## First concat, then sort

The method I'd use is to create a list of duplicate dataframes, `concat` them together, and then `sort_index`:

```
count = 5
new_df = pd.concat([df]*count).sort_index()
```

Comment: This is extremely inefficient via sort, see my answer for timings.

Answer (score 2):

Using `numpy.repeat` and `.iloc` In here, k=2

```
df.iloc[np.repeat(np.arange(len(df)), 3)]

Out[256]: 
   Index data1 data2 data3
0      0    x0    x0    x0
0      0    x0    x0    x0
0      0    x0    x0    x0
1      1    x1    x1    x1
1      1    x1    x1    x1
1      1    x1    x1    x1
2      2    x2    x2    x2
2      2    x2    x2    x2
2      2    x2    x2    x2
```

Comment: Added timings ;-)

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
Use `repeat` + `reindex` + `reset_index`:

```
df

  data1 data2 data3
0    x0    x0    x0
1    x1    x1    x1
2    x2    x2    x2

df.reindex(df.index.repeat(5)).reset_index(drop=1)

   data1 data2 data3
0     x0    x0    x0
1     x0    x0    x0
2     x0    x0    x0
3     x0    x0    x0
4     x0    x0    x0
5     x1    x1    x1
6     x1    x1    x1
7     x1    x1    x1
8     x1    x1    x1
9     x1    x1    x1
10    x2    x2    x2
11    x2    x2    x2
12    x2    x2    x2
13    x2    x2    x2
14    x2    x2    x2
```

---

**Option 2**
Similar solution with `repeat` + `pd.DataFrame`:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, 5, axis=0), columns=df.columns)

   data1 data2 data3
0     x0    x0    x0
1     x0    x0    x0
2     x0    x0    x0
3     x0    x0    x0
4     x0    x0    x0
5     x1    x1    x1
6     x1    x1    x1
7     x1    x1    x1
8     x1    x1    x1
9     x1    x1    x1
10    x2    x2    x2
11    x2    x2    x2
12    x2    x2    x2
13    x2    x2    x2
14    x2    x2    x2
```

---

**Comparisons**

```
%timeit pd.concat([df] * 100000).sort_index().reset_index(drop=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 14.6 s per loop

%timeit df.iloc[np.repeat(np.arange(len(df)), 100000)].reset_index(drop=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 22.6 ms per loop

%timeit df.reindex(df.index.repeat(100000)).reset_index(drop=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 19.9 ms per loop

%timeit pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values, 100000, axis=0), columns=df.columns)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.1 ms per loop
```